# Graph databases for sensor data - How to model the relationship?

Tags: graph-databases

I am currently evaluating possible NoSQL technologies for my usecase.
I have a lot of sensor data logs (several TBs) and want to analyze the data in a scalable, efficient way.

My sensor data contains a timestamp, Location, and a List of Sensor attribute name (for example "temperature") and Sensor attribute value (for example 12.9°C). However, the location is not present in all of my data entries. Also, the list of attributes per entry is varying. 
So one log entry could contain data like this:

- sensor_id: 1
- location: lat/lon (note: but not *always* included in each entry)
- datetime: timestamp_of_log_date
- attribute_name1: "attribute_value1"
- attribute_name2: 123123
- attribute_name3: 0.933
- attribute_nameN: "attribute_valueN"

I recently came across graph databases and find the concept interesting. I am not sure whether my usecase should be applied on a graph database because of (maybe) lacking relationships between my data.

There are some ways to model a relationship between my sensor data but right now I can only think of the following relationships:

- Date/Time of the entries to Year->Month->Day->Hour->Minute->Second
- Location of the entries to Continent->Country->State->City->Street/PoI
- Sensor ID->Attribute names

I am querying my data with geospatial queries, time queries and "normal" attribute queries (field_x <= 1000).

One more thing to note: When I'm running geospatial queries, I usually want to read out further records based on the timestamp of the record that was found in the spatial query. So basically, when my geospatial query finished and returns a record with timestamp "25.06.2016-20:40:30" I also want to read out ALL other records that have a timestamp within one minute for each record found in the geospatial query.

**Neo4j for example is good at processing geospatial queries, which is a pretty common query type for my usecase. But how would I model my data? How are my nodes connected to the other nodes? Do they even need to be connected?**

Comment: You can use spatial plugin for neo4j.
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial

Comment: While the looks that you do not need a graph database to work with this data.

Comment: @stdob I agree that I dont certainly _need_ a graph database to work with this data, but is it a bad idea?

Comment: " *Is it a bad idea?* " is strictly a matter of opinion.

Comment: I am also trying to do same thing with Neo4j, and I found a good article. if you are still interested in this topic, check out this link https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly find ways to model relationships with this data, the question what will you do with these relationships? If the relationships in your data are not of much value, then there is no point in using Neo4j(even though it is a great graph database!) for the sake of the spatial queries.

Neo4j really shines when you have connected data and there is value to be derived from those connections.

Comment: I have found a time-series usecase, described by the OrientDB team. They basically built their relationship like this: the time series nodes are year->month->day->hour and hour then links to a set of Log entries. That's almost my usecase, eventhough I'd enrich it with spatial data. There's one thing I'm not convinced of though... am I putting my location data as a property to my Log record or do I built another relationship for it? Would it affect querying a lot? See: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Time-series-use-case.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough knowledge of OrientDB to comment